# Setting Up Horizontal RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, padding, android-cardview

I want to add 10dp padding for my first tile in recycler View.

Just Like in the Book My show app the first App has 10dp padding (assume) then the padding between two tiles (suppose 5dp).

[image]

Similarly Last tile also have 10dp (assume) padding in the end

[image]

I'm adding my code of the recycler view If anyone wants to add something in it
**RecyclerMetroAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.android.indianmetro;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewAdapter";

private ArrayList<String> mPlaceNames = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> mPlaceImageUrl = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> mPlaceMetroDistance = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> mClosestMetro = new ArrayList<>();
private Context mContext;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> placeNames, ArrayList<String> placeImageUrl,
                           ArrayList<String> placeMetroDistance, ArrayList<String> closestMetro    ) {
    mPlaceNames = placeNames;
    mPlaceImageUrl = placeImageUrl;
    mPlaceMetroDistance = placeMetroDistance;
    mClosestMetro = closestMetro;
    mContext = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.horizontal_item, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder: called");

    Glide.with(mContext)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(mPlaceImageUrl.get(i))
            .into(viewHolder.placeImage);

    viewHolder.placeName.setText(mPlaceNames.get(i));
    viewHolder.placeMetroDistance.setText(mPlaceMetroDistance.get(i));
    viewHolder.closestMetro.setText(mClosestMetro.get(i));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mPlaceNames.size() < 8){
        return mPlaceNames.size();
    } else return 8;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView placeImage;
    TextView placeName;
    TextView placeMetroDistance;
    TextView closestMetro;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        placeImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        placeName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        placeMetroDistance = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        closestMetro = itemView.findViewById(R.id.placeMetroName);
    }
}
}
```

Code of tiles I'm using inside my RecyclerView

**horizontal_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView2"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/delhi1" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="India Gate"
    android:textColor="@color/darkHeading"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:text="2.4 Km Away"
    android:textColor="@color/blueAccent"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView2" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_metro"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/placeMetroName"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="Central Secretariat"
    android:textColor="@color/subHeading"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also if some one can suggest that how to make a tile fully visible from left and not allow any tile partially hidden from the left side

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can try to set the padding in `onBindViewHolder()`, 
for the first:

```
if (i == 0) 
    viewHolder.placeImage.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
```

and for the last:

```
if (i == mPlaceImageUrl.size() - 1) 
    viewHolder.placeImage.setPadding(5, 5, 10, 5);
```

Change the numbers to what you like they are **left->top->right->bottom** padding.

Comment: Do you have any idea about the animation (or whatever they call it) sifting tiles to make tiles always visible

Comment: I don't think so, but do post a question explaining what exactly you want. I'm sure that there are others here in SO who may help you.